# Id acumulador dentro de Clase Constructora en Js

Tags: javascript, html, array, dom, id

me gustaria recibir ayuda para poder generar un id acumulador dentro de una clase constructora en Js:

```
Class Consultorio {
constructor(id,nombre, sede, especialidades, horario) {
this.id = ;
this.nombre = nombre ;
this.sede = sede;
this.especialidades = especialidades;
this.horario = horario;
this.precio = especialidades === 'Clinica Medica' ? 3000 * 1.21 : 5000 * 1.21;
    };
};

Gracias,
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera agregar que has intentado para resolver el planteamiento dado

Comment: y también sería bueno que explicaras a que te refieres con "generar un id acumulador"? que es eso?

Comment: Te refieres a un ID que vaya incrementando a medida que vas creando objetos del tipo Consultorio?